# Import class dynamically with browserify on client side

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify, systemjs

I'm using browserify to create a bundle file of my app.
This app get from some rest a list of js file links, each link is a bundle of tool that my app should import and init the imported tool class.

My problem is that browserify doesn't support dynamically import/require like `require('www.example.com/myTool.js')`. It only knows to require modules from his bundle which I created on the build process.

Do you have any idea how I can keep using browserify and still require files on the fly? I try to import requirejs and systemjs but I had some problems to create a bundle with browserify.

I can force the tool's developers to support any kind of require mechanism, even something I can make. so fill free to write any kind of solution you think.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a problem with just using regular script tags which expose global variables?

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is one solution, but I'm trying to find a solution that use the require  mechanism and not to expose as a global variable. I even wrote a light require library, which is works, but I don't like to have my own require library while there are many other require library out there. I thought maybe I'm not the only one that face this issue.

Comment: Maybe you could take some inspiration from this: https://gist.github.com/rauchg/5b032c2c2166e4e36713?